# Low resolution textures on Ultra graphics settings?

Tags: metro-exodus

I have an RTX 2080 Ti and a high end Threadripper CPU. I can run Metro: Exodus on 1440p Ultra-wide with the Ultra graphics preset and RTX On at around 70-100 FPS quite happily.

However, I'm noticing really low resolution textures around the place. I have annotated some screenshots below (click the thumbnail to load the full-resolution images to see what I mean):

[image]

[image]

[image]

Are there any specific settings I should be looking at to fix this? Bumping the graphics level up to "Extreme" makes it *better* but it's still fairly obvious (and I lose about 20 FPS). It's breaking the immersion on an otherwise excellent game.

Comment: There might just be no really high quality texture available for these objects

Comment: @XtremeBaumer I considered that. These are just a few examples, but they are just everywhere. I would have thought that things like the LED and the Nixie tubes on the wristwatch would be as high as it comes due to the fact that it's basically part of the HUD and is used fairly constantly.

Comment: You could maybe replace the texture yourself with something of higher quality. Or someone else provides a patch to fix exactly these kind of graphic issues. Or you send an email to the developers and ask for a patch. Your best bet in the options is to turn literally everything to the max and see what happens.

Comment: Yeah I'm not about to go patching in hundreds of my own textures. I am not holding my breath that their support channels provide anything of any use either. Which is why I'm asking here - maybe others have seen similar issues and have found some setting that's causing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The setting you are looking for is (most likely) DLSS.

#### What is DLSS?

DLSS (Deep-Learning Super Sampling) is an Anti-Aliasing method that uses [**Deep Learning**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deep_learning) to upscale the rendered frame, thus reducing aliasing (aka. "jaggies"). It's also a method to increase performance.

What DLSS *really* does, is reduce the resolution your GPU is rendering at (thus improving performance), and upscaling the image to make it look like the game is still rendering at the same resolution. The technology isn't perfect, of course, but appears to yield better results (less quality loss) at 4k or higher resolutions than it does for lower resolutions (including 1440p).

Playing in 4k, I only noticed the negative effects of DLSS while trying to read Artyom's journal while the train was on the move. As the text was moving around, there was a very noticeable ghosting effect, making it very hard (and tiring) to read. After disabling DLSS, the ghosting was gone, and the text perfectly readable.

In any case, DLSS is the most likely culprit for any kind of visual degradation, especially concerning low resolution textures. That is, after all, precisely how DLSS works.

Comment: Great, I'll try disabling DLSS when I play again tonight. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: This is a definite improvement. Some of the items are still not great, but the vast majority are severely improved by disabling DLSS.